# Split EJB multiple JARs

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, ejb, ear

Is there a way to separate EJB among multiple JARs?
I want to modularize an EJB application but I want to load classes (session beans and entities from different JARs).

Therefore I have a parent EJB project and child modules.

```
EJB-PARENT
     |____jar module1
     |____jar module2
     |____jar module 3
```

I'm using Maven and an EAR to deploy EJBs and its children.

Comment: This should work. Depending upon your server implementation you may need to have properly composed `Class-Path` entries in your Manifest.mf files. It's not completely clear what your problem is. Have you actually tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I solved by using maven shade plugin to generate fat jar

Answer (score 0):

If you tought use multiple ejb jars in war files, then it is OK. Just build the EJBs into ejb jars and put them into the classpath of the WAR project. After that you can refer to the contained EJS-s.

But there is no way a tree like module structure as like in your diagram above.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you used Maven, It will be easy by following

You need to first established

Parent POM by using Maven inside Parent POM project, put all your dependency then create a modules like

```
parent-project[pom]:
     project-name-data.jar
     project-name-services.jar
     project-name-webservice.war
     project-name-ui.war
```

> For Your Session Bean

You can use them in `project-name-services.jar`

> For Your Entities

It can be managed in `project-name-data.jar`